# ipyleaflet TypeError: _handle_leaflet_event() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is my first try of ipyleaflet and i can not understand what is going wrong. I use jupyter notebook (from anaconda on ubuntu).

I have installed ipyleaflet:

> pip install ipyleaflet

then enabled it in jupyter notebook

> !jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix
>   ipyleaflet

and now when i try to use ipyleaflet with a simple python code:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map
Map(zoom = 4)
```

i get map and a lot of similar errors under the map:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: _handle_leaflet_event() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

What I get in notebook:
[image: Notebook]

Thank in advance for help.

Comment: May be something is in conflict? How can i check for this?

Comment: What is your version of ipywidgets? Did you try updating it?

Comment: Thanks for idea, I have ipywidgets 7.4.2

Comment: Thanks, also what is your version of ipyleaflet? `_handle_leaflet_event` takes 4 arguments since `0.5.1` if I'm correct, and the current version of ipyleaflet is `0.10.0`. It would be weird that you have a version of ipyleaflet that old though. I suggest you try updating it too. Or maybe use conda?

Comment: Unfortunately for me i have up-to-date ipyleaflet version 0.10.0. Also i've tried folium - it works normally.